# Android's AsyncTask issue

Tags: android, android-asynctask

could anyone advise on the following:
I'm trying to execute code from Android's help page, but it doesn't work for me:

```
public class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {
        protected Long doInBackground(String... urls) {
            Log.e("TuneWiki", "Exec");
            return 1l;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            Log.e("TuneWiki", "Post");
        }
}
```

when I execute task, doInBackground is invoked fine, but onPostExecute is never invoked :(

Tested on Milestone with 2.1 OS

Comment: hm. This looks ok to me so far. Could you post the code you are using to call execute(...). Also, for what it's worth, since you are not using the Progress type, you could say `<String, Void, Long>`

Comment: Here is another sample project using an `AsyncTask`: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Threads/Asyncer/

Comment: I found this link quite helpful. Scroll down till after threads. I think it might be what could help you understand the problem... http://www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android22Threads.html

Answer (score 6):

Thanks everyone - I found the reason. AsyncTask ceases working for some reason if a lot of threads were started before even if all threads were successfully completed.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to use AsyncTasks for file downloads (as the name of your AsyncTask suggests). AsyncTasks should not be used for long running operations such as networking. Indeed AsyncTask have two main issues that are related :

- they are poorly tied to the activity life cycle
- the create memory leaks very easily.

Inside the [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice) Motivations app ([available on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.octo.android.robospice.motivations)) we answer that question in detail. It will give an in-depth view of AsyncTasks, Loaders, their features and drawbacks and also introduce you to an alternative solution for network requests : RoboSpice.

We even provided [an infographics](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/wiki/Understand-the-basics-of-RoboSpice-in-30-seconds) to explain this issue. To put it in a few words

- AsyncTasks are flawed as they are poorly tied to Activity Lifecycle and create memory leaks
- Loaders are pretty good for what they have been designed for : accessing cursors of Sqlite databases, but don't offer any support for networking. They are the wrong tool for this.
- RoboSpice executes network requests in a service, your downloads are executed in an Android Service, memory is well managed and it even provides support for writing REST requests.

---

I encourage you to download the [RoboSpice Motivations app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.octo.android.robospice.motivations), it really explains this in-depth and provides samples and demonstrations of the different ways to do some background operations.