# None of my AsyncTasks are executing on PostExecute

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, ui-thread

The only AsyncTask that I have that is working properly is one that handles a progressdialog for a search. None of my other AsyncTasks are getting to onPostExecute() even though the doInBackground() is completing! I am pulling my hair out because it used to work in earlier commits and doing a compare, I see no difference! A lot of the AsyncTasks used to update correctly and call postExecute, now they update really slowly and only a few times, and never execute onPostExecute!

Comment: this question isn't showing up so commenting to make it appear :(

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365768/androids-asynctask-issue

Comment: I could not find any differences between when things were broken and when they worked. I ended up just reverting to an old revision where the threads were all working correctly, and have not had any problems since. I also have not changed how I was implementing the AsyncTasks. I am completely clueless, but happy to be done with it.

Comment: nevermind. I have a method that returns a value in doInBackground but then ASyntcTask never calls its onPostExecute...

Comment: voted to close since it looks like the author @Aymon sorted out an answer (but didn't post it)

Comment: Aymon Fournier: as a friendly reminder, can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.